# testing hello world in android using Juint

Tags: java, android

i am not really big  in java or android and i have beeen assigned a new tasks for testing a android "hello world" application , basically this test has to just check that a "hello world" is printed on the screen (Emulator) .

now i have been digging google for good 3-4 days , i guess this is a very simplistic task  , but somehow , it seems quite daunting to me ,  i have seem a few articles online about testing .

[testing in andorid](http://evgenii.com/blog/testing-activity-in-android-studio-tutorial-part-1/)

[android developers testing](https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-basic-testing.html) .

google really seems short on good resources on testing . can somebody give me a headstart in the right direction and tell me , how do i go about doing this simplistic task ? i basically just need to write a test that checks that "Hello world is printed to the screen".

The code i need to test :

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: How are you printing to screen?

Comment: @beresfordt no , it displays on the emulator !

Comment: I mean are you printing "hello world using `System.out` or something else android specific?

Comment: @beresfordt , no , "Hello world" is not printed to the console , it shows only in the emulator .

Comment: Could you include the code you wish to test in the question please